# Can not fill DataTable with json data

Tags: java, json, ajax, servlets, datatable

I am creating java web application. For display data in table i am using datatable plugin. Here is my function which send post to servlet and get json data. When i check returned json i see everything okay but i can not display this data in my datatable.

What is json return:

```
{"data":[{"id":32,"fullName":"Murad Heydarov Cefer","name":"Murad","surname":"Heydarov","middleName":"Cefer","department_name":"Proqramlasdirma","startedToWork":"11/03/2017","note":"must go this week"}]}

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "../employer/list",
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json",
        "success": function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    },
    "columnDefs": [{
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        }],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']],
    "columns": [
        {"data": null},
        {"data": "fullName"},
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "surname"},
        {"data": "middleName"},
        {"data": "department_name"},
        {"data": "startedToWork"},
        {"data": "note"},
        {"data": "id"}
    ]
   });
  });
```

Here is my Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    int worker_id;
    String str = (String) session.getAttribute("SID");
    SimpleDateFormat tsdf = null;

    if (u.module(request).equals("employer"))
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

        switch (u.view(request))
        {
                case "list":
                JsonElement workerListJson = gson.toJsonTree(workerAction.Connect());
                jsonObject.add("data", workerListJson);
                out.println(jsonObject.toString());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Jsp file:

```
<table id="example" class="ui celled table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>full name</th>
        <th>department name</th>
        <th>started to work</th>
        <th>days remain</th>
        <th>period</th>
        <th>times</th>
        <th>note</th>
        <th>action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>full name</th>
        <th>department name</th>
        <th>started to work</th>
        <th>days remain</th>
        <th>period</th>
        <th>times</th>
        <th>note</th>
        <th>action</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: Remove `"success": function (data) {` you should never ever address an AJAX `success` callback directly in DataTables since it can overwrite or disturb the internal logic. If you need a success handler use `dataSrc` instead.

Comment: Thanks dude its really helped me @davidkonrad